# loop, array and file problem in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, file-io

I'm currently learning ruby and here what I'm trying to do:
A script which open a file, make a subsitution, then comparing every lines to each other to see if it exist many times.
So, I tried to work directly with the string, but I didn't find how to do it, so I put every line in an array, and comparing every row.
But I got a first problem. 
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

DOC = "test.txt"
FIND = /,,^M/
SEP = "\n"

#make substitution
puts File.read(DOC).gsub(FIND, SEP)

#open the file and put every line in an array
openFile = File.open(DOC, "r+")
fileArray = openFile.each { |line| line.split(SEP) }
#print fileArray #--> give the name of the object
#Cross the array to compare every items to every others
fileArray.each do |items|
items.chomp
        fileArray.each do |items2|
        items2.chomp
                #Delete if the item already exist
                if items = items2
                        fileArray.delete(items2)
                end
        end
end
#Save the result in a new file
File.open("test2.txt", "w") do |f|
        f.puts fileArray
end
```

At the end, I only have the name of the array object "fileArray". I print the object after the split, and i've got the same, so I guess the problem is from here. Little help required (if you know how to do this without array, just with the line in the file, answer appreciate too).
Thanks !

EDIT:
So, here's my code now

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

DOC = "test.txt"
FIND = /,,^M/
SEP = "\n"

#make substitution
File.read(DOC).gsub(FIND, SEP)

unique_lines = File.readlines(DOC).uniq
#Save the result in a new file
File.open('test2.txt', 'w') { |f| f.puts(unique_lines) }
```

Can't figure out how to chomp this.

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using? 1.8 or 1.9?

Comment: I use 1.8.7. Should I update ?

Comment: No sorry..was thinking of something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code like this:

```
f.puts fileArray.join("\n")
```

Alternate way:

```
unique_lines = File.readlines("filename").uniq
# puts(unique_lines.join("\n")) # Uncomment this line and see if the variable holds the result you want...
File.open('filename', 'w') {|f| f.puts(unique_lines.join("\n"))}
```

Comment: Hmm, great, but I got an empty file in the end :/

Comment: Can you please tell us what is the value of the variable 'unique_lines'?

Comment: It still returns an empty file, but join is effective in the shell

Comment: I still see you missed the join statement in the f.puts call

Comment: OK, said nothing, it works, except it didn't "chomp" the lines

Answer (score 3):

Deleting duplicate lines in a file:

```
no_duplicate_lines = File.readlines("filename").uniq
```

No need to write so much code :)

Comment: Wow, ok, indeed, pretty awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Just a couple of points about the original code:

```
fileArray = openFile.each { |line| line.split(SEP) }
```

sets `fileArray` to a `File` object, which I suspect wasn't your intention. `File#each` (the `#` notation is Ruby convention to describe a particular method on an object of the supplied class) executes your supplied block for each line (it's also available with a synonym: `each_line`), where a line is defined by default as your OS's end-line character(s).

If you were looking to build an array of lines, then you could just have written

```
fileArray = openFile.readlines
```

and if you wanted those lines to be `chomp`ed (often a good idea) then that could be achieved by something like

```
fileArray = openFile.readlines.collect { |line| line.chomp }
```

or even (since File mixes in `Enumerable`)

```
fileArray = openFile.collect { |line| line.chomp }
```

And one other tiny thing: Ruby tests for equality with `==`, `=` is only for assignment, so

```
if items = items2
```

will set `items` to `items2` (and will always evaluate as `true`)